Access GPT4All local server
I've installed GPT4All, downloaded a model and already started chat with this model. I'm trying now to make API requests to its designated 4891 port but I'm getting 404 error. How can I achieve this?
public async Task<string> GetResponseAsync(string message)
{
    var payload = new
    {
        prompt = message,
        max_tokens = 100,
    };

    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:4891");
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(baseAddress, content);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseString;
}

